# Can Teysa, Orzhov Scion sacrifice itself and still use its 2nd ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens if I sacrifice [Teysa, Orzhov Scion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Teysa%2C%20Orzhov%20Scion) along with two other "white and black" creatures (in order to remove another creature from the game) - do I still get my 2 spirit tokens from the other two sacrificed white and black creatures, even though Teysa as well was sacrificed at the same time?

Or is it that when Teysa is sacrificed along with the other two, its 2nd ability doesn't count anymore?

Answer (score 5):

You will still get the 2 spirit tokens. This is because when creatures die (are put into the graveyard from the battlefield), the game checks what the state of things was just prior to the creatures leaving the battlefield to see if there is anything that needs to trigger.

> 603.6d Normally, objects that exist immediately after an event are checked to see if the event matched any trigger conditions. Continuous effects that exist at that time are used to determine what the trigger conditions are and what the objects involved in the event look like. **However, some triggered abilities must be treated specially. Leaves-the-battlefield abilities, abilities that trigger when a permanent phases out, abilities that trigger when an object that all players can see is put into a hand or library, abilities that trigger specifically when an object becomes unattached, abilities that trigger when a player loses control of an object, and abilities that trigger when a player planeswalks away from a plane will trigger based on their existence, and the appearance of objects, prior to the event rather than afterward. The game has to "look back in time" to determine if these abilities trigger.**

Comment: @Klausi, If this answers your question, please check the mark next to it. (If not, say what's lacking.) Welcome to B&CG!

Comment: Actually, the creatures don't go to the graveyard at the same time because of rule 601.2g, so rule 603.6d doesn't apply here.

Comment: I would think that "Sacrifice 3 creatures" counts as all 1 cost, not 3 separate costs to be paid in any order. But I could see it either way. 601.2g isn't clear on this, do you have another reference?

Comment: Actually, 603.6d is still needed, because the triggered ability isn't put on the stack in the middle of paying the costs anyway. It is added to the stack after Teysa's ability.

Comment: If my answer were right (I now agree that it isn't, so I have deleted it), 603.6d would not be relevant, because the time when an ability is put on the sack is not the same that the time when an ability triggers, and 603.6d is only about the latter.

Comment: @Pablo, good point.